# ¿Cómo pasar objetos a través de un socket, cliente-servidor en C#?

Tags: c#, xml, socket, serialización

estoy trabajando con C# en un sistema de votación y necesito pasar información encriptada obtenida desde una base de datos en MySQL a través de sockets, sin que lo tenga que hacer por partes.
El error que me dice *es que no encuentra el ensamblado de mi archivo XML.*
¿Alguien me puede ayudar? soy nueva en esto, gracias de antemano...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de sockets, tu debes garantizar la estructura de tu trama. ya que al final todo pasa como bytes, en ese orden de ideas lo que sugeriria que hicieras es suponiendo que se envia el mensaje desde el cliente hacia el servidor:

Cliente

- Convertir tu objeto a byte[]
- Calcular cuanto mide tu array de bytes y agregar este numero como parte de tu trama como byte[].
- Hacer alguna operacion logica que te permita generar un checksum y agregarlo a tu trama
- Podria poner una trama inicial que conozca para identificar cuando es un objeto tuyo

Servidor

- Buscar la trama inicial y el numero que indica cuanto mide tu objeto
- Extraer la trama que corresponde a el objeto y hacer la misma operación que hiciste para generar el checksum
- Comparar el checksum contra el que agrego a la trama, deberían ser iguales, si no entonces puede que se haya dañado la trama o que no ha llegado completa, así deberias volver a leer el socket
- si el checksum coincide y es la misma trama, deberías poder convertir a tu objeto